# Loading a html script from a typescript file

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, chatbot

Im am currenlty working on a integration of a nps widget within a Chatbot. I cannot show you all the code, but i imported the html file inside the chat.ts file. I want to call the entire html file after a button press from the chatbot. I have tried a lot, but nothing seems to help.

this is the chat.ts code (small part of it)

```
 private showAskNicely() {

        // @ts-ignore
        window.location.assign('npshtml.html');
    }

    private askNicelyButton() {
        const el = document.getElementById('detractbut');

        el.addEventListener('click', this.showAskNicely);

    }
```

this is the npshtml file

```
<html>
<body id="try">
<p>
    AskNicely Web Survey Popup Example for traditional websites.<br>
    Running in 'force' mode.<br>
    Responses will be recorded.
</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.asknice.ly/dist/standalone/asknicely-in-app-conversation.js"></script>
<link href="https://static.asknice.ly/dist/standalone/asknicely-in-app-conversation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

        askNicelyConversation({
            config: {
         --- cannot show this part  --- 
            },
            customData: {
                a_custom_property: 'business', // Optional - Send extra data about this customer for reporting and leaderboards
                another_custom_property: 'New York' // Optional - Send extra data about this customer for reporting and leaderboards
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have the button rendered inside another html file with css, but that all works fine.

I have it currently on windows.location.assign, so that it opens a new page. It would be ideal if the script could be triggered without opening a new page.

Using jquery.load does not work and does not give me a error of some sort.

Comment: "Nothing seems to help" sounds vague. What happens if you execute that script?

Comment: I changed the way showAskNicely works quite some times. I never got a error. The way it is currently set up it only shoots the page to Cannot GET /npshtml.html. I also tried calling the html part with Jquery.load